# Append element into a json object python

Tags: python, json

I have a Json object and Im trying to add a new element every time I enter a new number. The Json looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "range": [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
]
```

This is my code:

```
import json

number = raw_input("enter a number: ")

json_file = 'json.json'
json_data = open(json_file)
data = json.load(json_data)
data.append({"range": number})
print data
```

If my new number is 10 for example, I want my new json document to have: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10`]. The output I'm getting with my code is:

```
[{u'range': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, {'range': '25'}]
```

I'm using python 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
data[0]['range'].append(10)
```

Or use `int(your_number)` instead of `10`

Comment: Its appending! but Im getting it like a char: [{u'range': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '10']}]. How can I change it to a number?

Answer (score 1):

Your json object consists of:

- single element list
- first element of list is mapping with single key (range)
- this key value is a list

To append to this list you have to:

- take first element from list - `data[0]`
- take a correct value from mapping - `data[0]['range']`
- append to retrieved list - `data[0]['range'].append(new_value)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all for opening a file you can use `with` statement which will close the file the the end of the block, the you can load your json file and after that you can will have a list contains a dictionary which you can access to dictionary with index 0 and access to the list value with `data[0]['range']` and finally you can append your number list :

```
import json

number = raw_input("enter a number: ")

json_file = 'json.json'
with open(json_file) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    data[0]['range'].append(int(number))
print data
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I need! I will accept your answer as soon as I can.